# Calculate Number of weeks

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I Have a table called Calendar and the data looks Like:

```
Date                         Week_Num       Month_Year
1996-01-27 00:00:00.000      1021            01/1997
1996-01-28 00:00:00.000      1021            01/1997
1996-01-29 00:00:00.000      1021            01/1997
1996-02-03 00:00:00.000      1022            01/1997
1996-02-04 00:00:00.000      1022            01/1997
1996-02-10 00:00:00.000      1023            01/1997
1996-02-11 00:00:00.000      1023            01/1997
```

I want to calculate the Number of weeks in a month_year:

I wrote a query like:

```
Select Month_year,Count(*)
From (Select Week_Num,Month_year
      From Calendar
      Group By Week_Num,Month_year
      )a
Group By Month_year
order by Month_year
```

This is giving me what I want but is there a better way  of doing it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT Month_Year, COUNT(DISTINCT Week_Num)
FROM Calendar
GROUP BY Month_Year
```

This removes one level of aggregation and is much more readable.  I'm not sure if it would perform any better, though.

**SAMPLE FOR PROOF OF CONCEPT:**

```
DECLARE @t table (DT smalldatetime, week_num int, month_year varchar(100))

INSERT INTO @t
VALUES
('1996-01-27 00:00:00.000', 1021,'01/1997'),
('1996-01-28 00:00:00.000', 1021,'01/1997'),
('1996-01-29 00:00:00.000', 1021,'01/1997'),
('1996-02-03 00:00:00.000', 1022,'01/1997'),
('1996-02-04 00:00:00.000', 1022,'01/1997'),
('1996-02-10 00:00:00.000', 1023,'01/1997'),
('1996-02-11 00:00:00.000', 1023,'01/1997')

SELECT Month_Year, COUNT(DISTINCT Week_Num)
FROM @t
GROUP BY Month_Year
```

**Returns:**

```
Month_Year  (No column name)
01/1997         3
```

Comment: You beat me by 32 secs, argh! :)

Comment: @JNK nope this is not what I want For example in the above data the otput should return me 3 since the Month_year 01/1997 has three weeks in it.

Comment: @Peter - what does it return then?

Comment: @JNk My Bad I was using Week_num and Month_year in group by. Sorry about the confusion and Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

I this is what you need:

```
Select Month_year,Count(distinct Week_Num)
From Calendar
Group By Month_year
order by Month_year
```

Comment: nope this is not what I want For example in the above data the otput should return me 3 since the Month_year 01/1997 has three weeks in it.

Comment: @Peter have you tried running this? I does return 3 for 01/1997!